# How can I apply multiple filters for logs in tortoise svn (e.g. revision number, filename, developer/coder)?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I want to filter out the subversion logs by my teammate & only for UI files i.e. HTML files in TortoiseSVN's repo browser.

Instead of manually reviewing the check-ins & see the file names under each revision can I apply multiple filters to get the desired results in one go itself.

Currently I can apply filter on Author or file names but not both simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it. Click on the search icon to select which information you want to search in, and to choose regex mode. Normally you will only need a simple sub-string search, but if you need to more flexible search terms, you can use regular expressions. If you hover the mouse over the box, a tooltip will give hints on how to use the regex functions, or the sub-string functions. The filter works by checking whether your filter string matches the log entries, and then only those entries which match the filter string are shown.

Simple sub-string search works in a manner similar to a search engine. Strings to search for are separated by spaces, and all strings must match. You can use a leading - to specify that a particular sub-string is not found (invert matching for that term), and you can use ! at the start of the expression to invert matching for the entire expression. You can use a leading + to specify that a sub-string should be included, even if previously excluded with a -. Note that the order of inclusion/exclusion is significant here. You can use quote marks to surround a string which must contain spaces, and if you want to search for a literal quotation mark you can use two quotation marks together as a self-escaping sequence. Note that the backslash character is not used as an escape character and has no special significance in simple sub-string searches. Examples will make this easier:

```
Alice Bob -Eve
```

searches for strings containing both Alice and Bob but not Eve

```
Alice -Bob +Eve
```

searches for strings containing both Alice but not Bob, or strings which contain Eve.

```
-Case +SpecialCase
```

searches for strings which do not contain Case, but still include strings which contain SpecialCase.

```
!Alice Bob
```

searches for strings which do not contain both Alice and Bob

```
!-Alice -Bob
```

De Morgan's theorem-> NOT(NOT Alice AND NOT Bob) reduces to (Alice OR Bob).

```
"Alice and Bob"
```

searches for the literal expression “Alice and Bob”

```
""
```

searches for a double-quote anywhere in the text

```
"Alice says ""hi"" to Bob"
```

searches for the literal expression “Alice says "hi" to Bob”.